# Audio not working when casting YouTube embedded in Google Slide

Tags: audio, casting, youtube

Issue is as follows:

ChromeOS v98 onwards (maybe earlier)
In Google Slides, insert a YouTube video. Cast to a screen, audio only plays on the chromebook not the tv you are casting to
Windows laptop with up to date chrome, casting via chromecast does same thing
ChromeOS v89 is ok

Webpage with an embedded YouTube video is fine, as is casting directly from YouTube

Comment: issue presents at ChromeOS 93 onwards. Audio is fine with HDMI cable. Seems like ChromeCast. I'll test a few older versions of Chrome Browser on Windows as well

Comment: Chrome Browser on Windows version 92 is fine, version 93 has the issue